# jQuery multiple file selector to work as "one after another"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im looking for an fairly simple solution to allow users select files one after another in `input type="file"` as UX analysis shown that only few people understand how to use it holding the key shift or ctrl to select multiple files at once.

Currently if user choice one file, than click select again and choice another file, it overrides previous value.

**HTML**

```
<div class="fileform-multiple">
    <input multiple="multiple" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" class="inputfile" name="photos[image][]" type="file" id="listing_photos_attributes_1_image">
    <label for="file" class="form-control">Choose a file</label>
    <div class="selectbutton">Choose photo</div>
    <small>Maximum 5 files, each less than 2Mb</small>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll( '.inputfile' );
Array.prototype.forEach.call( inputs, function( input ){
    var label    = input.nextElementSibling,
        labelVal = label.innerHTML;

    input.addEventListener( 'change', function( e ){
        var fileName = '';
        var errors = 0
        $.each(e.target.files, function( index, value ) {
            var ext = value.name.split( '.' ).pop().toLowerCase();
            if ($.inArray(ext, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) == -1) {
                alert('invalid extension! Only .png, .jpg and .jpeg allowed ');
                errors ++
            };
        });
        if (errors > 0){

        } else if (this.files && this.files.length > 5 ) {
        alert('Please select less than 5 files');
        } else if( this.files && this.files.length > 1 ) {
            fileName = ( this.getAttribute( 'data-multiple-caption' ) || '' ).replace( '{count}', this.files.length );
        } else{
            fileName = e.target.value.split( '\\' ).pop();
        }

        if (errors > 0){

        } else if( fileName ){
            label.innerHTML = fileName;
        } else {
            label.innerHTML = labelVal;
        }

        var strToPrepend = fileName + ' ,' + "<br/>"
        $(this).closest('.fileform-multiple').find('small').prepend(strToPrepend);
    });
});
```

Comment: After a user closes file dialog there is no way modifying what file(s) were chosen so adding/deleting wont work , only way I see is when user finishes selecting a file dynamically create new file input and on submission they all get sent at once

Answer (score -1):

Cant you use some open-source solution for dragging/uploading multiple files? There must be plenty of them out there. For instance first i found in google: http://www.dropzonejs.com/

Comment: Will not work as I need fairly simple solution. Have no need in adding 50kb of extra code that I will never use :)